# Android navigationView when is visible on screen listener

Tags: android

Is there a listener for navigationView if it is actived (Is visible on screen)?
I tried setonsystemuivisibility but not works.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I need listener to be called when it's on screen and when it's gone.
thanks.

Comment: Use `addDrawerListener` in your `DrawerLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `DrawerListener`:

```
    mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() 
    {
        // other overridden methods not shown 

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) 
        {
            // drawer opened
            // todo: announce for accessibility 
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hope This will help you**

```
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public static ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;


mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);



mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(FragmentHomeActivity.this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name){


                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                    //calling onDrawerClosed, when View gone invisible

                }

                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // calling onDrawerOpened, when View visible
                }
            };
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

**If you are using `Toolbar`, then**

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```